# I am getting the following error when uploading a large mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I am seeing the following error on mysql after uploading a very large database (~500MB). Can anyone help me upload this database?

> ## 2006 - MySQL server has gone away

Under that i see another error:

> Warning in ./libraries/classes/Dbi/DbiMysqli.php#213
> Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=9196

Answer (score 0):

**How do I fix the error “Mysql Server has gone away”?**

The `MySQL server has gone away (error 2006)` has two main causes and solutions:

Server timed out and closed the connection. To fix, check that wait_timeout MySQL variable in your `my.cnf configuration` file is large enough.
Server dropped an incorrect or too large packet. If mysqld gets a packet that is too large or incorrect, it assumes that something has gone wrong with the client and closes the connection. To fix, you can increase the maximal packet size limit `max_allowed_packet` in `my.cnf` file, eg. `set max_allowed_packet = 128M,` then restart your MySQL server: `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

[reference](https://matomo.org/faq/troubleshooting/faq_183/)